# UV Map / Rig problem

Tags: uv, rigging, armature

I'm new at it at all.

1. So I just want to know how to remove these vertices safely, I need just edges, but not inside grid.
2. About Armature. Why it's position is not like object position on my screen?

[image]

upd. I have re-created the rig and the new character model, but when I tried to apply it to the character and move his parts, they are being distorted. Video: [streamable.com/47pueb](https://streamable.com/47pueb)

I have noticed one thing, when i use vertices, then armature are able to rotate it smooth, but how to apply the texture to the model when there a lot of vertices? It looks like on my picture above.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, in the 3D Viewport, select the whole mesh in Edit Mode, press <kbd>X</kbd>, then select `Limited Dissolve`.

For the second issue, while in Edit Mode, by default, the mesh shows up in the unmodified state (for the armature modifier). To show it in the modified state, click the corresponding button on the modifier.

[image: Modifier]

Please note that there are other possible causes for the second issue. Please let me know if the suggestion above doesn't resolve your issue.

---

**Update:** The following is a list of things I would do differently when creating an asset for games.

1. Place the origin for the armature and mesh at the bottom of the character's feet.

[image: Origin]

2. Remove extra edge loops that won't contribute to the deformation (nor have an effect on shape).

[image: Extra Edge Loops]

3. Pick descriptive names for the bones.

[image: Bone Names]

4. Remove bones that won't contribute to the character's deformation.

[image: Extra Bones]

5. Pick a consistent orientation for the bones (by adjusting the bone roll). The z-axis points back for most bones, but points right or left for the legs.
6. Adjust the bone hierarchy.

[image: Bone Hierarchy]

The character will look like this. Note that fixing the bone roll now will break the animation, so I didn't do it.

[image: Final]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150159/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-a-uv-map-rig-problem); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.